# Debugging user-code on xv6 with gdb

Tags: gdb, qemu, xv6

I'm doing an OS class that's based on xv6 and I wrote a program that needs to run on it.

I know that I can debug kernel code with `make qemu-gdb` but I'm not sure how to debug my own user program.

Lets say I want to debug `cat`, how would I go about doing that?

Thanks

P.S. isn't there an xv6 tag? should this question even go here?

Comment: `:file cat`, `:break main`, `run` gets something?

Comment: Okay, now I feel really stupid because I was sure I tried that. But now I think that it might be that i tried `load` instead. Thanks! I looked for this everywhere online, even emailed some people, no one could tell me this... (Answer and I'll accept.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`file cat`, `break main`, `continue`

semi reference [running and debugging xv6](https://web.archive.org/web/20190308091152/http://zoo.cs.yale.edu:80/classes/cs422/2011/lec/l2-hw)

Comment: When I tried it I needed to do 

`file _cat
break main 
continue`

This is because _cat is the name of the file on the host

By the way this is run in the gdb window (so you've run make qemu-gdb, then in another window you've run gdb kernel).

Answer (score 16):

From the xv6 top-level dir:

1. Run the emulator in debug mode (assuming no X11): `make qemu-nox-gdb`
2. In other terminal just run the debugger loading the kernel symbols with:
      `gdb kernel` *This is important, otherwise the debugger will be confused between kernel and and user program symbols, for example `main()`*
3. From the gdb interface run: `(gdb) target remote localhost:26000`
   *where 26000 is the TCP port that the step #1 report at the end (this might change).*
4. Load the user exec with `(gdb)file user_program`
5. Place a breakpoint `(gdb) break main`  and continue with `(gdb) continue`
6. etc...