# how can I add breakpoint into files when debugging xv6 using GDB?

Tags: debugging, operating-system, gdb, xv6

I run `make qemu-gdb` to prepare xv6 for debugging and then in another terminal with opened in the same directory (in xv6 dir) I enter ```gdb`` and I get this output:[image: gdb]

just for more info, seems like it connects to debugging process automatically and when I enter  `target remote TCP::26000` it wants to end this process.

now my actual problem is here when I enter something like `b cat.c:12` it says that source file cat.c doesn't exist (which I'm sure is not true and happens for every file I enter instead of cat.c); although I can put breakpoint for some functions such as `fork` or `exec`.

I don't know where the problem is. could you help me to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debugging user-code on xv6 with gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534798/debugging-user-code-on-xv6-with-gdb)

Comment: no, after entering `file cat`, I'm still unable to  set `b cat.c:12`

Answer (score -1):

actually, I found a solution but that's not what was on my mind. We can use `symbol-file _<program name>` which in my case, it's `symbol-file _cat` and now we are able to set a breakpoint like `break cat.c:12`.

but I wanted gdb to load all of the symbol files by itself.